# Mathcad automatic conversions

Tags: data-conversion, mathcad

Can someone tell me how to use value in degrees as if it was normal value?
Example:

```
 x := 15deg
`y := 4 * (x + 15)
```

And I want y to be equal 120.

Answer (score 0):

in second equation 15 is a number not degree add deg in second equation

```
    x := 15deg
   `y := 4 * (x + 15deg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Ivan's answer, Mathcad automatically converts degrees to radians, so you're actually adding 15 degrees expressed in radians to 15 (radians).   Whilst Mathcad will normally flag up unit mismatches, radians have Dimension 1 (ie, they are dimensionless), and Mathcad treats them as just numbers (as per the SI).

Here's a hopefully more explanatory Mathcad version of the above!

[image]